# Jquery multiple elements get triggered when hovering a single element

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-transitions

I am creating multiple cards, and when I hover over one of the cards, the image inside the card gets bigger and I've done that on Jquery. My problem is when I placed multiple cards and hover on a single card element, all the rest of the cards also gets triggered. Is there any way to fix this other than having separate classes for each card in CSS?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cardjs-1,.cardjs-2').mouseover(function() {
    $('.cardimage').addClass('card-js-hover');
    $('.cards').mouseout(function() {
      $('.cardimage').removeClass('card-js-hover');
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.cards-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 3fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 80px 10px #a29d9d;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cardimage {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: border-radius .1s, width .1s, height .1s;
}

.card-js-hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn-book {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #F25F5C;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cards-container">
  <div class="cards cardjs-1">

    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/338515/pexels-photo-338515.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="paris-image" class="cardimage">
    <h4>PARIS</h4>
    <p>$500/4 days</p>
    <a class="btn-book" href="#">Book Now</a>
  </div>
  <div class="cards cardjs-2">

    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2570063/pexels-photo-2570063.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="cardimage">
    <h4>BERLIN</h4>
    <p>$200/3 days</p>
    <a class="btn-book" href="#">Book Now</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because you select all the elements, not the one related to the one you are hovering. And you should NEVER bind another event inside another. You are going to hjave tons of event listeners added./

Comment: You can easily do this with just css. FYI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you're selecting all `.cardimage` elements. Just select the one relevant to the hovered `.cards` element using the `this` keyword and jQuery's `find()` method.

Also note the use of the single `.cards` selector and `hover()` and `toggleClass()` in the below example to simplify the logic.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cards').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.cardimage').toggleClass('card-js-hover');
  });
});
```

```css
.cards-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 3fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 80px 10px #a29d9d;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cardimage {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: border-radius .1s, width .1s, height .1s;
}

.card-js-hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn-book {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #F25F5C;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cards-container">
  <div class="cards cardjs-1">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/338515/pexels-photo-338515.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="paris-image" class="cardimage">
    <h4>PARIS</h4>
    <p>$500/4 days</p>
    <a class="btn-book" href="#">Book Now</a>
  </div>
  <div class="cards cardjs-2">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2570063/pexels-photo-2570063.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="cardimage">
    <h4>BERLIN</h4>
    <p>$200/3 days</p>
    <a class="btn-book" href="#">Book Now</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

***However***, it's worth noting that you don't need JS for this. You can achieve the exact same effect in CSS alone. This has the benefit of not relying on JS to make the UI work and also performing *much* better as CSS is hardware accelerated, JS is not.

```css
.cards-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 3fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 80px 10px #a29d9d;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cardimage {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: border-radius .1s, width .1s, height .1s;
}

.cards:hover .cardimage, 
.card-js-hover {
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn-book {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #F25F5C;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cards-container">
  <div class="cards cardjs-1">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/338515/pexels-photo-338515.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="paris-image" class="cardimage">
    <h4>PARIS</h4>
    <p>$500/4 days</p>
    <a class="btn-book" href="#">Book Now</a>
  </div>
  <div class="cards cardjs-2">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2570063/pexels-photo-2570063.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="cardimage">
    <h4>BERLIN</h4>
    <p>$200/3 days</p>
    <a class="btn-book" href="#">Book Now</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer and sorry for the late reply, My Internet is down. Can you clarify about `this` keyword? What's the difference between `this` and my `.cardimage` class?

Comment: The answer explains it; `$('.cardimage')` selects every element with that class that exists in the DOM. Within the event handler, `this` refers to *only* the `.cardimage` element which raised the event

Answer (score 1):

You can use just css selector `.cards:hover .cardimage`:

```css
.cards-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px;
}

.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 3fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 80px 10px #a29d9d;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cardimage {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  transition: border-radius .1s, width .1s, height .1s;
}

.cards:hover .cardimage{
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.btn-book {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #F25F5C;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cards-container">
  <div class="cards cardjs-1">

    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/338515/pexels-photo-338515.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="paris-image" class="cardimage">
    <h4>PARIS</h4>
    <p>$500/4 days</p>
    <a class="btn-book" href="#">Book Now</a>
  </div>
  <div class="cards cardjs-2">

    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2570063/pexels-photo-2570063.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" class="cardimage">
    <h4>BERLIN</h4>
    <p>$200/3 days</p>
    <a class="btn-book" href="#">Book Now</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer and sorry for the late reply, My Internet is down.